# How to hide navigation bar on android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I need to enable full screen mode  without navigation bar on android which placed in the bootom of the screen. (Like on clash of clans game).
I don't know how can I do this in cocos2dx. Kindly suggest.

Comment: how android and coco , this funny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your question about android then that is the answer

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

if you want full screen For window (Ex: web view .....)

```
int width = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width;
int height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height;

[yourWindow setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height) display:YES];
```

You can refer to some tutorial teach you how make your window full screen

[tutorial-making-your-mac-app-support-full-screen-in-1-minute.html](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/mac-os-x-development/86282-tutorial-making-your-mac-app-support-full-screen-in-1-minute.html)

[ios-7-tutorial-series-gestures-and-fullscreen-layouts](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/joshua-huerkamp/ios-7-tutorial-series-gestures-and-fullscreen-layouts)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb2ywxOnFZE